# How to delete lines between different clusters of timestamp in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

As you can see below:

[image]

There are a lot of lines between different clusters of timestamp, which is so ugly from my perspective, Could I delete it?

Comment: actually, many things depend on your datasource. If you remove lines and leave only points, will it solve your problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your support. Certainly I want to remain lines rather than just points, I used Influxdb and timestamp data won't be transfered in only one series.

Comment: i had the similar issue, and solved it in the following way. i wrote zero values with time stamp, where there was no data, and chose option not to show zero values.

Comment: Thanks. Will volumes of data be too high because of adding too many zeros? or just add zero in the beginning and end of timestamp clusters

Comment: In my case i had plenty ofspace and didn't care about it, but maybe your scenario with one zero will work too. But if you use some agregaton finctions of your datasource, one zero solution may fail